# Python: list of list __getitem__

Tags: python

I've created a `Board` class for a connect 4 game that makes use of a list of lists. I'd like to have the object support indexing for both the rows and the columns of the board:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, cols, rows):
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        self.data = [[' '] * cols for row in range(rows)]

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.data

    def __getitem__(self, row):
        pass
        # what should this be?
```

I know I need to define `__getitem__` but what should this method be to allow syntax such as `b[1][1]`? I've taken a look at [some past questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032493/getitem-with-slices-on-a-list-of-lists) but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

**Edit**: maybe the following is the correct way to do things?

```
def __getitem__(self, row):
    return self.data[row]
```

Comment: `b[1][1]` is two `__getitem__` calls, one for `b[1]` and the other calling `__getitem__` on the result of that.  Your list of lists can't control what they both do.  The easiest thing is to make your `__getitem__` accept a tuple so that you can do `b[1, 1]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental thing you need to understand is that for syntax like `b[1][2]`, there are *two* `__getitem__` calls. First, `b.__getitem__(1)` is called, and that returns an object. Then, `returned_object.__getitem__(2)` is called. So, whatever class `b` is does NOT have full control over this whole process.

In your example above, if you defined it as

```
def __getitem__(self, row):
    return self.data[row]
```

then `b[1][2]` would first call `b.__getitem__(1)`, which would return `self.data[1]`, which would be a list. That list also supports `__getitem__`, and so next `list.__getitem__(2)` would be called.

If you want control over *both* of those, then you need to define another class that represents columns, the parent class would need to return one of those objects instead of the raw list, and then that one can implement its own `__getitem__` for custom functionality.

Other choice is to support syntax like `b[1,2]` which is legal - it will call `b.__getitem__((1,2))` with `(1,2)` as a tuple (you can put *anything* in there really), but it's not as natural.

Comment: Couldn't you use a `@classmethod` decorator and pass the class? Then you could return another instance of the same class.

Comment: Well, if you use a `@classmethod`, then it can only use class (not instance) variables in the function, and all instances of the class will get the same result - probably not what you want. But you're on the right track - you can have `__getitem__` (that is not a @classmethod, just a regular descriptor) on a class, create another instance of the same class. For instance, in `etree.Element`s, calling `element[0]` will return another `Element` that is the first child, and this can be nested as deep as desired.

Answer (score 4):

You can return the `row` that's represented by the sublist

```
def __getitem__(self, row):
    return self.data[row]
```

For example

```
>>> t = Test(2,5)
>>> t.data
[[' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ']]
```

Getting a row

```
>>> t[1]
[' ', ' ']
```

Getting an element

```
>>> t[1][0]
' '
```

Note that the second operation, `[0]` in the example above, doesn't need you to define it because it will simply call `__getitem__` from `list` because that's what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Just return the row:

```
def __getitem__(self, row):
    return self.data[row]
```